# Can I preload a formula for a future tab

Tags: worksheet-function

I am building a template workbook with a summary table of preloaded formulas to extract desired info from a sheet that is yet to be pasted.  I am getting a #REF! result because the source info is not there yet- hasn't been pasted in.
Example is that a worksheet is pasted into the workbook primary source tab, a macro is then run to create several other tabs that break down the source info into totals in the same location, i.e. TabX!P5 or TabY!P5.  But my summary sheet referencing TabX!P5 and TabY!P5 is not there yet (because its a template) so i get the #REF! result.  Is there a way to create a formula referencing a cell in a tab that doesn't yet exist without rewriting all my summary formulas.  The summary table cell still gives a #REF! even after the source is pasted.

Answer (score 1):

When a formula is calculated, Excel will try to resolve any reference. If the sheet that a formula references does not exist, the reference will not resolve and will return an error. Excel does not keep the erroneous reference, so creating the sheet after the #REF! error has occurred will not make the error go away.

Just like you would when manually building a workbook, first create the sheets, then create the formulas that reference the sheets.

So, don't paste the summary table until all other sheets that are referenced in the summary table are present.